# UILongPressGestureRecognizer switch between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I've put `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to appear `uimenucontroller` on `uitableview` cell when I switch from view controller to another view controller it doesn't appear. Why?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellNotificationTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [self longPress:recognizer];
return cell;
}

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
 UITableViewCell *cell2 = (UITableViewCell *)recognizer.view;
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
       // UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)recognizer.view;

        UIMenuItem *flag = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" action:@selector(DeleteMsg:)];
        UIMenuItem *approve = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Read" action:@selector(ReadMsg:)];
        UIMenuItem *deny = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"UnRead" action:@selector(UnReadMsg:)];

        UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flag, approve, deny, nil]];
        [menu setTargetRect:cell2.frame inView:cell2.superview];
        [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
    }
    selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell2];

    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)selectedIndexPath.row);
    NSUserDefaults *nssave = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [nssave setInteger:selectedIndexPath.row forKey:@"selectedcellrow"];

}
```

Comment: I think the call to [self longPress:recognizer]; is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your asking but when you set up your gesture recogniser you set the target to be self (I.e. The current view controller). So if you change view controllers the target is no longer around.

Comment: Right if view controllers changed tbe target is no longer around